# Resize range, copy and paste new range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through the rows of an Excel worksheet, select a row of data as a range, copy and paste it into the desired worksheet.

I am currently trying the below method which gives an error on the `.Resize()` part.

```
With ws1
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Set rng1 = .Range("A" & i).Resize(0, 16)
        rng1.Copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(destination).Range("A" & lastRow2 + 1)
```

I get a 1004 error on the third line. I am using the copy/paste methodology from earlier in the code, so I think that is working correctly.

I have tried to use:

```
Set rng1 = .Range("A" & i)
rng1.Resize(0, 16)
```

and also

```
Set rng1 = .Range("A" & i)
Set rng1 = rng1.Resize(0, 16)
```

but I get the same error each time. I know this is likely a simple syntax issue but I've spent the past 20 minutes looking online and cant figure out what the solution is.

I have thought about maybe trying the `EntireRow` method but I am stubbornly trying to understand what is wrong with my current methodology.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using Resize without 0 in that way `Set rng1 = .Range("A" & i).Resize(, 16)`

Comment: You can't resize to zero rows, has to be at least 1, as per YasserKhalil's comment.

Comment: Yep, this was exactly my issue! Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Per YasserKhalil (and SJR) you cannot resize to zero, so just omit the zero and change to `Resize(, 16)`